# React - Passing fetched data from API as props to components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Iam trying to understand and learn how to pass around data as props to other components to use. Iam trying to build a top-level hierarchy where the API Request is made in a class at top level and then the result is passed around to child components to be used as props and then in states.

The problem is that when i pass the result i get **"Object Promise"** in my child component. **How do I access the data sent as props to child components?**

As you can see in my **App.js** in my render() method that i created a component of the class API and pass the result from the **fetchData()** method as parameter to the component.

**In my API.js class i used console.log** to check the result but
the result i get from the logs are:

**line 5:** {dataObject: Promise}

**line 10:** undefined

**App.js:**

```
import API from './API';

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData();
  }


  fetchData(){
      const url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=50&nat=us,dk,fr,gb";
      return fetch(url)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(parsedJSON => console.log(parsedJSON.results))
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <API dataObject={this.fetchData()}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**API.js**

```
import React from 'react';

class API extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        console.log(props);
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataObj:props.dataObject
        };
        console.log(this.state.dataObject)
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <p>""</p>
        )
    }
}

export default API;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing App.js to this:

```
import API from './API';

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData();
  }


  fetchData(){
      const url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=50&nat=us,dk,fr,gb";
      return fetch(url)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(parsedJSON => this.setState({results: parsedJSON.results}))
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <API dataObject={this.state.results}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This makes sure you fetch the data in `componentDidMount` and it now uses `state` to store the data which then will be passed into your `API` component.

Comment: Did you make any changes in the App.js class? To me it seems there is no difference between mine and yours?

Comment: By passing `fetchData` in as a prop in that way, you're causing it to fire everytime the component is re-rendered.

Comment: @RileySteeleParsons sorry, I meant to change that but undid it. I've updated it

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is looking for an answer using Hooks then this might help.

**App.js**

```
import API from './API';

function App(props) {

  const [result, setResult] = React.useState({});

  // similar to componentDidMount
  React.useEffect(() => {
    this.fetchData();
  }, []);


  fetchData() {
      const url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=50&nat=us,dk,fr,gb";
      fetch(url)
          .then(response => setResult(response.json()))
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
  return (
      <div className="App">
        <API dataObject={result}/>
      </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**API.js**

```
import React from "react";

function API(props) {
  
  const [result, setResult] = React.useState(props.dataObject);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setResult(result);
  }, [result]);

  return <p>{result}</p>;
}

export default API;
```

Hope it helps! And let me know if anything is incorrect.

Comment: So you create a container component solely to hold the data as props? Kinda a makeshift/hacky context sorta thing?

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch data in `componentDidMount` and not in `render`. Fetching the data within render causes the API request to be repeated, **every** time the DOM is re-rendered by react.js.

After making the `GET` request to the API endpoint, first parse the data into a javascript object, then **set the results to `state`** using `this.setState` from within your component.

From there, you may pass the data held in `state` to child components **as props** in the `render` function.

For example:

```
const App = (props) => 
    <ChildComponent />

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            results: []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('/api/endpoint')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(results => this.setState({results})
    }

    render(){
        return <GrandchildComponent {...this.state} />
    }

}

const GrandchildComponent = (props) => 
    <div>{props.results}</div>
```

Comment: Ok i will try this method but the thing is that at the top level in the hierarchy i dont want the class to have state. In this case I dont want App.js to have states, I want it to be stateless. Only the child components should have states

Comment: This is a fantastic tutorial on using APIs in a React component: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-fetching-data/

Comment: OK, then make `App` a functional stateless component, and then delegate all the API requests to the child component, which will hold the API results in state.

Comment: I mean i could have a state at the top level but is that the React way of doing things? or should the top level always be stateless and only the children should have states? 

How do you mean with your solution? How do I delegate the API requests to the child component?

Comment: I would recommend that you hold the fetched results in the `state` of the greatest common ancestor of components that require the data. So if you only need the API results in a single child component, just handle the request there, store it in its state. That way you can just have a stateless `App` component (you create these in the same way you create a normal javascript function, with props as the only argument, and returning whatever you wish to render, in this case your component that makes the API call).

Comment: @gtag There's no one size fits all! However, it wouldn't make sense to move all your state to the top level app container, since it would balloon really quick.